# Screen Reader(VoiceOver in iOS) ignores `alt` if inside `label`

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

I have a radio button with 2 languages to select. When I test in VoiceOver on iPhone then `alt` attribute value is ignored and VoiceOver reads just 'image' without 'Deutsch':

```
<label for="lang-de">
  <img src="assets/imgs/sprache_deutsch_icon.svg" alt="Deutsch" />
</label>
```

As a workaround I tried to use aria-hidden attribute for image and absolutely positioned text inside `label` but then when user selects the text by double tap radio option is not selected like it did when user selected image:

```
<label for="lang-en">
  <span class="sr-only">English</span>
  <img src="assets/imgs/sprache_englisch_icon.svg" aria-hidden alt="English" />
 </label>
```

Is it expected behavior because `label` text suppresses the `alt` value or am I doing something wrong here?

Any advices would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an interesting case.  It only appears to be an issue when the image is an SVG.  It works fine for PNG and JPG.  I hear the "interactive" and "bbc" labels but just "radio button" for the w3c logo.

```html
<input id="test1" type="radio" name="a">
<label for="test1">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000443220383/4e56ac181c96ad9997a47de74c1d2c6e_normal.png" alt="interactive">
</label>

<input id="test2" type="radio" name="a">
<label for="test2">
  <img src="https://www.w3.org/StyleSheets/TR/2016/logos/W3C" alt="w3c" width="50">
</label>

<input id="test3" type="radio" name="a">
<label for="test3">
  <img src="http://static.bbci.co.uk/wwhp/1.123.289/responsive/img/apple-touch/apple-touch-180.jpg" alt="bbc" width="50">
</label>
```

A few things you can try, depending on if you have access to the SVG.  (I haven't tried these)

1. Add `role="img"` to the `<svg>` tag.  That might trick VoiceOver into thinking it's more like a PNG or JPG.

```html
<svg role="img" ...>
```

2. Add a `<title>` element to the `<svg>` with your alt text, such as:

```html
<svg ...>
  <title>Deutsch</title>
```

3. In addition to the `<title>`, add `aria-labelledby` to the `<svg>` that points to the title (and add an ID to the `<title>`):

```html
<svg aria-labelledby="foo" ...>
  <title id="foo">Deutsch</title>
```

4. Using an SVG is great because it scales well for low vision users if they have to magnify the font, but I suppose a last resort would be to convert your SVG to a PNG or JPG.  It won't look as nice when you magnify it (unless you save it as a large image), but it's certainly another possibility.

Comment: `role="img"` worked for me, thanks a lot for thorough answer

Comment: Glad the easy suggestion worked.  You might want to try it on Internet Explorer.  By default, an `<svg>` is a focusable object (on IE) so you might end up tabbing to the radio button widget and then tabbing to the svg.  However, by specifying `role="img"`, that might prevent the svg from being a tab stop.  If it doesn't, then you'll have to add `focusable="false"` to the `<svg>`.

Comment: Thanks for another valuable tip. Luckily my app is an Ionic app which means no IE support :-P

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that SVG is a vector file format, that is infinitely scalable without loss of quality, but the others are not.

JPG is a file format witch uses a real compressing method without changing the color depth. It can reduce the file size dramatically, infinitely variable, but in the same way with loss of quality. Usually JPG is recommend on photos, because of there wide color profile. A JPG with 80% compression could have a small loss of visual quality which most people don't recognize at all.

You can use the PNG 24bit for photos as well, but with bigger file size.

Additionally you can use PNG 8bit for graphics like logos or charts. There the color palette is reduced to 256 optimized/selected colors. The loss of visual quality is lower on graphics, because they already come with fewer colors.

In any case, it remains a case to decision, and yes I'm a designer.